# What is a computationally cheap way to update the screen every x% of the way through a list

Tags: c#, responsive-design, progress-bar, iteration

I have a list of IEnumerable and I have to do a long running operation on each item in the list. The list may have anywhere between 50 and 50 million items in it.

I have the total count of objects in the list, and I am using a foreach to iterate through the list.

I would like to write to the console every x% of the way through the data, with the x being more often with bigger sets of data and less often with small sets.

It would be a bonus to have the writes exactly the same distance apart (i.e. 10% 20% for 100 items and 1.01% 1.02% for bigger sets)

Be gentle, this is my first SO question! :)

Comment: The problem is you have to know how many items you need to iterate over. Do you know that before you start? Also, `IEnumerable<T>` is just a take-next. If you `.Count()`, you could end up doing a very long running query to get the number.

Comment: I DO have the count of the objects in the list, obtained in a different way, but that is outside the scope of the question. Please assume there is an Int32 that contains the count

Comment: Why you want it to be so accurate? In many scenarios, you simply output once per several operations (number depends and I can assure you, nobody is trying to find that number to be perfect, its purpose is simply not update *too much/less often*). And if you want to count it more less precisely, then measure time after *each completed operation* and see if you are over next *threshold increment* value.

Comment: You are right, perhaps i'm overthinking this a bit. Im just thinking that if the operation is fast and i have 50mil items to process, then i can update say every 30000 operations, but if the list is only 500 items, then updating after 30000 is kinda pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the total count of objects in the list, and I am using a
>   foreach to iterate through the list.

then you already know the number of items to process, so an obvious solution would be:

```
int total = theList.Count;
int done = 0;
foreach (var item in theList)
{
    Process(item);
    done++;

    // Outputs progress
    double percentage = done / total * 100;
    Console.WriteLine(percentage);
}
```

Then you could use a modulo to avoid updating the UI (or console or whatever) every time:

```
if (done % 1000 == 0)
{
    // Outputs progress only 1 out of 1000 times
    double percentage = done / total * 100;
    Console.WriteLine(percentage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. My problem would seem to be determining what size modulo to use? I want to update the screen often, but not constantly - with preferably an equal jump between points

Comment: @OP, don't output by using modulo criteria, count time and output after certain period of time is expired.

Comment: @user230910 One simple solution would be to use a "fixed step", so you would update every 1% or 0.1%. The constant value for the modulo operation would then be "total / 100" or "total / 1000". That being said, this wouldn't work if the time to process each item is not constant.

Comment: In my case the time to process is more-or-less fixed, so this will really help thanks!